# Android Mupdf 1.3 Annotations

Tags: android, annotations, mupdf

With the latest version of mupdf (1.3), annotations are supported.
Though i dont know how.

Did someone use them already?
All samples so far were running on 1.1 without any code regarding annotations and theres no documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: did u found any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

Oh nvm, just look at the git repo and youre done